# Algolia search: access results onclick

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, search, algolia

I am using [algolia search](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails) for my rails app, I sat up the auto completion method using [typehead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). But I can't redirect properly when I have uppercase in the URL... Here is my code:

```
    // replace YourIndexName by the name of the index you want to query.
var index = algolia.initIndex('Pin');

// Mustache templating by Hogan.js (http://mustache.github.io/)
var template = Hogan.compile('<div class="hit">' +
  '<a href="http://yhumans.com/{{{twitter}}}">'
 +
  '<div class="small-text">' +
    '{{{ _highlightResult.name.value }}} ' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="small-text">' +
    '@' +
    '{{{ _highlightResult.twitter.value }}} ' +
  '</div>' +
  '</a>' +
  '</div>');


// typeahead.js initialization
$('#user-search').typeahead(null, {
  source: index.ttAdapter({ hitsPerPage: 5 }),

  displayKey: 'twitter',
  templates: {
    suggestion: function(hit) {

      // select matching attributes only
      hit.matchingAttributes = [];
      for (var attribute in hit._highlightResult) {
        if (attribute === 'name' || attribute == 'twitter') {
          // already handled by the template
          continue;
        }
        // all others attributes that are matching should be added in the matchingAttributes array
        // so we can display them in the dropdown menu. Non-matching attributes are skipped.
        if (hit._highlightResult[attribute].matchLevel !== 'none') {
          hit.matchingAttributes.push({ attribute: attribute, value: hit._highlightResult[attribute].value });
        }
      }

      // render the hit using Hogan.js
      return template.render(hit);

    }
  }
});
```

The problem is with this lines that I am using to let the user click on results to access page:

```
<a href="http://yhumans.com/{{{twitter}}}">'
```

In fact some of my users has capitalize letters in their twitter usernames, So I can't redirect properly to their profiles on search results.

Let me explain: http://yhumans.com/myname is a correct URL. http://yhumans.com/MyName is a wrong URL
 I tried to use lowercase for that variable: "twitter". But I could not find a way to do it properly.

I know that one way to do it would be to lowercase the twitter variable. But the thing is that the function 'downcase!' doesn't seems to works in js.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, two comments that won't answer the question directly, but are related:

- with Hogan templates, you should use `{{variable}}` when the text shouldn't have HTML in it, and `{{{variable}}}` when it should. That's why you should use `{{twitter}}`.
- Algolia has actually forked `typeahead.js@0.10` into [`autocomplete.js`](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js), you should have a look at that.

That being said, you gave one solution, even if you are right, `.downcase!` doesn't exist, it's actually [`.toLowercase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
In your suggestion function, just lowercase the `twitter` attribute that way:

```
function (hit) {
  hit.twitter = hit.twitter.toLowerCase();
  // ...
}
```

One issue with that way of handling the autocomplete redirection is that the user won't be able to use his/her keyboard to chose the result. The recommended way with both `autocomplete.js` and `typeahead.js` is to use, respectively the [`autocomplete:selected`](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#with-jquery) or [`typeahead:selected`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/300) event:

```
$('#user-search').typeahead(/* ... */).on('typeahead:selected', function (ew, selection, dataset) {
  // Redirect to http://yhumans.com/my-twitter-name
  window.location.href = 'http://yhumans.com/' + selection.twitter;
});
```

To display the current selection to the user when he/she hovers or picks the result with the arrows, you can put a different background color with `.aa-hint` (`autocomplete.js`) or `.tt-hint` (`typeahead.js`).

Comment: Yes that's a tough one. For now I'll just roll with the LowerCase solution, It works quite well even with the downside > No keyboards commands. I guess you answered my question. Thank you !